# Ubuntu-Windows Public Folder File Share

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-8, samba, file-sharing

I have created a network share folder in my Ubuntu 14.04, I downloaded Samba and created a username and gave it a password. I have Windows 8 able to see it and add credentials.

But after I enter in the credentials it states that Windows 8 cannot connect to the computer and keeps asking me to check if its connected. How do I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to access it previously? Or you creating it firstly?

Comment: This is all creating it first try. So no I wasn't able to access it previously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed description of accessing samba from Windows8. I'm using this method and works pretty fine!

create one user in `ubuntu` server

`#useradd smb1
 #passwd smb1`

Set the password accordingly

`# smbpasswd -a smb1`

For example, set the password as `samba123$`.

Add a user to a Samba share

Open via vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

`[accounts]
comment = Accounts data directory
path = /home/tester
valid users = smb1 smb2 smb3
public = no
writable = yes`

Save the file

Then Restart samba service!

`/etc/init.d/smbd start
/etc/init.d/nmbd start`

Then try in windows!

Comment: does it matter if its not a server? Seems like I can do all this on 14.04 but I'm just making sure

Comment: It should work. Hope you're accessing as follows `\\<IP_Ubuntu>\accounts`. While prompted for credentials, you must provide the username as `smb1` and `password` you set while executing this cmd `# smbpasswd -a smb1`

I edited as per my commands I've written in the reply.

Comment: I've tried this link and then your directions. I get the same error coed: 0x80070035. states that the network path cannot be found. This happens when I go to Network and click on my Ubuntu computer name. It also happens when i try to map a network drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

Comment: error pops up through windows btw

Comment: I believe you are providing the username and password as `\smb1`(to ensure it is not in any domain) and the password as `samba123$`. Also, did you try to add that drive as mapped drive? or Just accessing as UNC share?

Comment: i tried as a map drive and on windows under the network tab in file explorer. I've tried again and I still get it saying it cannot connect to my ubuntu. They are both on the same wifi network and i dont get how it cannot connect. Is this a windows to linux network problem possibly?