# Ubuntu / Windows 8 Folder Sharing, "Windows cannot access ..."

Tags: networking, windows-8

I'm trying to set up a shared folder on my Ubuntu machine, and access it from my windows 8 machine, as per the instructions on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows?lq=1). I've done the setup process on the ubuntu machine, the folder properties looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to connect to windows, I get this:

[image]

Also, my windows computer just isn't detecting any other computers on the network, other than itself:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things, like disabling the windows firewall, disabling the ubuntu firewall, entering the local IP instead of the computer name, [manually configuring samba files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859721/wind), [reinstalling libtalloc2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802927/windows-cannot-access-samba-server), [adding samba users and restarting the service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542940/ubuntu-windows-public-folder-file-share), etc etc.

I'd really appreciate help.

**-UPDATE-**

Pinging the name andromeda doesn't work, pinging the local IP does.[image]
But even if I substitute the server name for the IP, I run into the same problem[image]

**-UPDATE-**

I have the exact same situation when I try to access the server from my windows 10 laptop.

Comment: That is the first link in my post, it is what i was trying to do when i ran into this problem

Comment: Can you ping the name `andromeda` from the other computer?  There is a chance that DNS may not have a record for it and you might have to access it via the IP address.

Comment: I've updated the post with that info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I found that there is a small addition I needed to make to the proposed duplicate answer:  In the [global] section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, add two lines:  `encrypt passwords = true`  and `wins support = yes`.  The samba service needs to be restarted after this.  `sudo service smbd restart`

Comment: Ok, I've done that, it didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I solve the problem :) https://askubuntu.com/a/1205660/477066