# Windows 10 share no access

Tags: networking, samba, windows-10, shared-folders, plex

Attempting to move media from Windows 10 to Ubuntu folder on the same network. I created a share user name/password and can log into the server, but have no access to the folder from Windows.

Image with error:

[image]

Well, I was able to finally access windows from Ubuntu, but not the other way around. I know the username and password are there, but maybe not associated with samba and the folder correctly.

Edit with share screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit with usershare output:

```
[{Plex}]
path=/media/aldimere/ef018901-2b4c-41f4-ba56-f17a751c0a3a/{Plex}
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

Comment: Looked at the linked post for permission and everything looked to match up correctly.  Ubuntu ---> Windows (Works) &  Windows ---> Ubuntu (Still gives the no permission error on the shared folder.

Comment: Edit your post one more time please and add the output of this command: `net usershare info --long`

Answer (score 1):

The system will block everyone except aldimere from getting to anything past /media/aldimere.

You can either mount the partition somewhere else like /media/ef018901-2b4c-41f4-ba56-f17a751c0a3a

Or you can edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this line:

```
force user = aldimere
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```